# Query to collect logs for last 10 mins in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7

I am looking to find logs from MongoDB for last 10 minutes using python script. The query I am using in MongoDB is getting an empty response:

```
db.alerts.find({
    "alerted_at": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2016-08-02T23:50:21.774531")
    },{ "$lt": ISODate("2016-08-02T23:55:21.774531") }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you are using is wrong, the `$lt` operator needs to be within the same document as the `$gt`:

```
db.alerts.find({
    "alerted_at": {
        "$gte": ISODate("2016-08-02T23:50:21.774531")
        "$lt": ISODate("2016-08-02T23:55:21.774531") 
    }
})
```

For an actual query that looks for logs from MongoDB for last 10 minutes:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
db.alerts.find({ "alerted_at": { "$gt": start, "$lte": end } })
```

Comment: I have used same but mongodb is giving time greater than defined. I need to collect logs for last 10 minutes.For e.g Logs in time between Time T-1 to T-2.

Comment: "db.alerts.find({"alerted_at":{"$gt":(datetime.datetime.now()),"$lt":(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(minutes=5))}}"                          Above mentioned query worked for me.